# SWI-Prolog give me False message

Tags: prolog

> Define a sum_threshold (List, Threshold, Sum) predicate to sum the
> elements of List that have a value greater than or equal to the
> Threshold.

```
sum_threshold([Head | Tail], Threshold, Sum) :-
    Head >= Threshold,
    sum_threshold(Tail, Threshold, Sum2),
    Sum is Sum2 + Head.
sum_threshold([Head | Tail], Threshold, Sum) :- 
    Head < Threshold,
    sum_threshold(Tail, Threshold, Sum).
```

I have compiled the file on SWI-Prolog, but when I do:

```
sum_threshold([5,3,10,4,7,1], 5, Sum).
```

It gives me

> False

Why??

Comment: What's your default case?

Comment: And your alternative when `Head < Threshold`.

Comment: @Enigmativity I have edited the first question. Did you thing that the false message is why Head < Threshold?

Comment: I add also the `Head < Threshold` case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the default case when the list is empty. You need this:

```
sum_threshold([],_,0).
```

I then get:

```
?- sum_threshold([5,3,10,4,7,1], 5, Sum).
Sum = 22 .
```